# How to allocate less processing power to a video conversion process?

Tags: temperature

I do a lot of video converting on my laptop, and I notice that during conversion the temperature of the processor is between 90C-99C, which is a bit alarming for me.

I am using Windows 8.1 and I can't find any option in task manager to limit computational resources. My current fix for this is to disable hyper-threading and turbo-boost in BIOS setup which helps to limit CPU temperature around 80C, but it also reduces overall speed of my computer.

Is there another way of doing this within Windows for a single process?

Comment: What are you using to convert the video? Although your question asks about how to limit a particular process, there may be a way within the software you are using to set a limit.

Comment: That said, there's a [question about limiting an arbitrary process](http://superuser.com/questions/214566/are-there-solutions-that-can-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process) which may address what you need.

Comment: If you are using FormatFactory, theres an option to set the priority.

Comment: These temperatures are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

In windows in the power propeties , you can set the "Processor Power Management" , "Maximum Processor State"  to 99% and at least on the computers here it will stop the processor from going into turbo modes.    then using techniques shown in the link below, you can create shortcut buttons to easily switch between power profiles live , when you wish to reduce the load.

In the same section "system cooling policy" you can switch to passive, which will slow the processor with stepping down, instead of ramping up the fans, dependant on OS connection to the fans.  This would probably NOT be useful in your situation, and also will adjust oddly when a processing load continues at a high rate.  If you are set to passive with this item, it could be part of the problem, it is one thing to check for how it is set, and the effect it has.

These OS control methods are really nice ways to control without having to do so in the bios.
[Easy way to switch power plan in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957500/easy-way-to-switch-power-plan-in-windows-10/957520#957520)

Both affinity and priority can be played with in the task manager , by right clicking on a process to see what possible effects it can have with a program and your system. A person can start by playing with this live in the regular task manager. In the next section though it is covered how to set things up to work that way without going to the task manager.

It is assumed your using a processor with more than one core, so using "start" to start a high load process would allow for many parameters. Changing the affinity to one core (same as one hyperthread) would reduce any multithreaded process to one core, reducing the heat some for a single (multithreaded) process. [How do I permanently set the affinity of a process?](https://superuser.com/questions/908848/how-do-i-permanently-set-the-affinity-of-a-process)  Even a single threaded process forced to only one core can restrict it some, and slow it in windows systems, so it is still worth a try on non-multithreaded programs to play with affinity.

Setting the priority of the process to low or idle class will reduce it only some. Priority does not stop things from using 100% of the processor, it only sets the specific program back in prioroty some, which can slow it down a little depending.  At least with prioroty you set high load tasks to the background, making it easier to continue with other tasks. (does not slow down the whole computer as much) [How can I tell Windows to always start certain binaries with low priority?](https://superuser.com/questions/83148/how-can-i-tell-windows-to-always-start-certain-binaries-with-low-priority/83150#83150)  (see  the simple start command usage in the 2nd part of the question)
For more information start with typing >Start /?  in the cmd prompt.

Start and powercfg items can be put into (seperate) shortcut icons to switch stuff and start stuff without an actual batch, as the shortcuts will take an amasing ammount of stuff in them if done properly.   So many icons could be made with different power profiles. Icons could be made for any program using "start" to provide a bit more control (affinity and priority) over a program.  If the program starts another program or task (child) then other measures would have to be taken.

There are programs that specialise in controlling the CPU use by any single program [Are there solutions that can limit the CPU usage of a process?](https://superuser.com/questions/214566/are-there-solutions-that-can-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process) Most of these programs work with the system, so they are limited to much the same things you can do yourself, and already in the task managers, but may very well be worth trying for your specific needs.

While 80C may be an great temperature to max out at, it is not always going to be possible to keep it that low. A additional laptop cooling thingee, which does what it can to extract more heat, could be used in a desktop setting. Cleaning the laptop and fan and heatsink would be regular maintance items.  Redoing the whole cooling setup (a complex and warrenty destroying task) could improve things easily.  Reducing general ambient temperatures in the room could be handy.

Other stuff:
Changing hyperthreading on or off , will not have much results in changing things. some programs may use more Or Less cpu total when hyperthreading is not engaged, depending completely on how the program is created , if it is multithreaded to begin with, and how it works with the hyperthreading system.  Some programs will work a bit faster with it off, some a bit slower, and the work is the heat.  Using Start affinity is one live way to contain a program to a single core, live in the system, but it is not the same as adjusting hyperthreading on-off in the bios.

If the heat is more about the GPU use, there are many GPU overclocking programs, and the GPUs own softwares that can control the stepping on the GPU items also. By UNDERclocking a GPU you can reduce the heat by volumes. The same programs used to overclock, can underlock (to lock manual lower) the GPU speed manually including the video ram rates to throttle the GPUs.   If the heat is due to  high use of a GPU item, controlling the GPU would have a large effect on overall heat.