# set affinity for program with bat, not working

Tags: affinity

I want to create a .bat file for a program as opposed to having to instruct a someone how to set affinity himself. This is a program that can crash when it uses too many cores due to an elusive bug (only with AMD processors?). Not a work related thing by the way.

I've been trying some variations of the setaffinity command but can't get it to work. Each time i check the task manager details it has all cores checked.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start /high /affinity 1 program.exe
start /affinity 3 program.exe
start /affinity 1F program.exe
```

None of these seem to work in my case for some reason...

Comment: Please check my answer at https://superuser.com/questions/908848/how-do-i-permanently-set-the-affinity-of-a-process/908870#908870

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I permanently set the affinity of a process?](https://superuser.com/questions/908848/how-do-i-permanently-set-the-affinity-of-a-process)